# Запуск bat-файла на удаленном сервере

Tags: php, bat, exec

Как запустить bat-файл на удаленном сервере через ssh2 php?

Comment: Какая ОС на удаленном сервере?

Comment: Windows serv 2012

Comment: Если включен safe_mode в настройках веб-сервера, то никак и не получится.

Comment: Запуск dir выполняется

Comment: `cmd /c "c:\\full\\path\\to\\my\\bat\\file.bat"`

Comment: О работает) спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $run = cmd /c "c:\\full\\path\\to\\my\\bat\\file.bat";
    exec($run);
?>
```